# Where's the .ssh/authorized_keys file of a non-login user?

Tags: linux, git, ssh

In my git docker container, I create a non-login user `git`.

In /etc/passwd file:

    `git:x:997:996::/tmp/git:/usr/bin/git-shell`

I want to log into git with RSA instead of password.

I append the id_rsa.pub key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` both under `/tmp/git` and `/home/git` ( user `git` is a non-login user. So I create this directory).

But both are not work!

I try to do it with the user `root`, I append the rsa.pub key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

It works!

So where's the .ssh/authorized_keys file of a non-login git user?

On the other hand, in my computer (remote to the git server), `ssh -p 2222 -Tv ssh://git@100.200.100.20`

it requires password.

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/Aario/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 100.200.100.20 [100.200.100.20] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Aario/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/Aario/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Aario/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Aario/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Aario/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Aario/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Aario/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Aario/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 1e:f3:f2:6b:45:95:b9:95:f1:ed:da:77:23:cc:d2:11
debug1: Host '[100.200.100.20]:2222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/AAario/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/Aario/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Aario/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Aario/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Aario/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@100.200.100.20's password:
```

In the git server container, I login with user `root` ,and I try these:
`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /tmp/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and `ssh -Tv git@localhost`. It says:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 1e:f3:f2:6b:45:95:b9:95:f1:ed:da:77:23:cc:d2:11
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@localhost's password:
```

Comment: What does `echo ~git` say?

Comment: In the docker container, it says `/tmp/git`

Comment: Well then `/tmp/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` is the right place.

Comment: I create the `/tmp/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and set its owner to `git`. The permission on `/tmp/git/.ssh` is 700 and on `/tmp/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` is 600. But When I push the git files, it requires password...

Comment: What is the output (you can edit your question) of `ssh -Tv git@your_container_ip`

Comment: It says that it requires password as above.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the permissions on the .ssh directory and the keys file are correct: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37164/ssh-and-home-directory-permissions

Comment: I create the /tmp/git/.ssh/authorized_keys, and set its owner to git. The permission on /tmp/git/.ssh is 700 and on /tmp/git/.ssh/authorized_keys is 600. But When I push the git files, it requires password...

Comment: @AarioAi: What happens if you try to ssh there without using git?  Just regular ssh git@host?

Comment: You're using ssh wrong.  Read the docs for it.

Comment: I reedite the question. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `/tmp` directory is probably world writable.

Were you to `man sshd`, you might notice a section at the bottom which includes:

> **~/.ssh/**
>           This directory is the default location for all user-specific configuration
>           and authentication information.  There is no general requirement to keep the
>           entire contents of this directory secret, but the recommended permissions
>           are *read/write/execute for the user, and not accessible by others.*

The hint you can take from this is that *permissions are important*. Now think about the location of the home directory of this user. Who has write permission to your `/tmp` directory?

Check your ssh server's authentication log (perhaps /var/log/security or /var/log/auth.log) and see if you see messages regarding permission errors.

If sshd can't trust that a user's configuration hasn't been tampered with, it refuse access.

Comment: The permission on /tmp/git/.ssh is 700 and on /tmp/git/.ssh/authorized_keys is 600. I can't find other log files except git log under /var/log in my docker container.

Comment: The permission on /tmp/git/.ssh is 700 and on /tmp/git/.ssh/authorized_keys is 600.

Comment: What about permission on `/tmp` ? And what does your log say?

Comment: I change its owner to 'git', and its mode is 700. I can't find any log in the docker container about sshd.

Comment: Then perhaps it's time to recognize that this question is off-topic for StackOverflow, since it's not about programming. I recommend you delete it here, then ask where to find your sshd logs on http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://ServerFault.com.

Comment: Thank you. I realize the diffirence between these two sites now. I have no permission to delete this question because of the exist answers. I won't confuse these two sites any more.